# Selector for selecting different text inside of a paragraph tag

Tags: web-scraping, css-selectors, selector

I am scraping a website and am trying to select each bit of text inside of the paragraph, but the text needs to be selected and handled differently on each side of the span tag. I have tried numerous types of CSS selectors and have not been able to figure out a way to do so. Is it possible to select `ASCEND` and `Bergamo, Italy` separately? Each instance on the website I am scraping will be different.

```
<p class="jv-job-detail-meta">
  ASCEND        

  <span class="jv-inline-separator"></span>
  
  Bergamo, Italy
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't tagged any language, I have a solution using Python.

You can do like this.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = '''<p class="jv-job-detail-meta">
  ASCEND        

  <span class="jv-inline-separator"></span>
  
  Bergamo, Italy
</p>
<p>
Public Relations
 <span></span> 
Atlanta, Georgia
</p>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')
p = soup.find_all('p')
for i in p:
    print(list(i.stripped_strings))
```

```
['ASCEND', 'Bergamo, Italy']
['Public Relations', 'Atlanta, Georgia']
```

Comment: And if the text is like `<p>Public Relations <span></span> Atlanta, Georgia</p>` it would work the same?

Comment: Yes, it will. I have updated the answer. Please check. Also it would be better if you share the URL instead of code snippets.